# Calling API data from kendo-ui chart series

Tags: javascript, kendo-ui

Is there a way to refresh the charts with remote data if you don't use datasource but instead dynamically create a series set with the return data from the API?  What I would like to do is have call the API again and rebuilt the chart.

Comment: Can you share the relevant code with us?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using Aurelia, there is a 3rd party bridge between kendo and aurelia called the [aurelia-kendo-bridge](https://github.com/aurelia-ui-toolkits/aurelia-kendoui-bridge).  When using that they have a recreate() function that can be run to reload the charts.  I just had to target all my charts and it worked.  Thanks very much @Jeroen Vinke for all the help.

Answer (score 0):

using this you can call the api from controller and if you want live update try to refresh the chart at particular time.

```
 $("#chartere").kendoChart({
              dataSource: {
                  transport: {
                      read: {
                          url: '@Html.Raw(@Url.Action("method", "controller"))',
                          dataType: "json"
                      }
                  },
                  group: {
                      field: "title",
                      Color: "Color"
                  }
              },

              seriesDefaults: {
                  type: "bar",
                  stack: {
                      type: "100%"
                  }
              },
              series: [{
                  field: "value",
                  colorField: 'Color',
                  groupColor: function (item) {
                      var series = item.series;
                      series.color = series.data[item.index].Color;
                  }
              }],

              categoryAxis: {
                  field: "Category",
                  majorGridLines: {
                      visible: false
                  }
              },

              valueAxis: {
                  line: {
                      visible: true
                  },
                  minorGridLines: {
                      visible: true
                  }
              },
          });
```

and use this for refresh the chart

```
chart.dataSource.read();
chart.refresh();
```

please check this url 
http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/dataviz/ui/chart#refresh

Comment: What if datasource is not used but instead we use series and place the data in the series?  How do you refresh the series?  Example: http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/bar-charts/index

Answer (score 0):

Every kendo widget have a [setOptions](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/dataviz/ui/chart#methods-setOptions) function that allow you to change the widget's option the same way you initialized them.  You'll be able to replace the series using that function.

```
$("#chart").kendoChart({
    series: [{
        data: [1, 2, 3]
    }]
});

var chart = $("#chart").data("kendoChart");
chart.setOptions({
    series: [{
        data: [4, 5, 6]
    }]
});
chart.refresh();
```